# How to execute certain code at the beginning of every theorem?

Tags: macros, amsthm, patching

I would like to inject certain code at the beginning of the environment `theorem`, defined with `amsthm`'s `\newtheorem`.

> In my case, the code I wish to add is `{\itemize\item[]\null\enditemize}\smallskip`, to make my theorems automatically have a new line after the theorem heading.

However, as this environment has an optional argument, it seems that I cannot use the hooks or patch them. Below are two ideas:

1. Add the code within `\theoremstyle`. This seems to be the best approach but I cannot make it work. (This failure approach is the one demonstrated in the MWE below)
2. Use `\RenewDocumentCommand` or `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` to redefine it. However this would be very complicated as there are many theorem-like environments to be redefined.

Below is a MWE, **the point of this question is to make the style `break` also works when the theorem begins with an `itemize` or `enumerate` list**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtheoremstyle{break}
    {}{}
    {\normalfont}{}
    {\bfseries}{}
    {0pt}
    {{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\nobreakspace #2}}%
      {\thmnote{\hspace{.4em}$($#3$)$}}%
      \smallskip%
      \newline%
      {\itemize\item[]\null\enditemize}\smallskip
    }

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}%{\itemize\item[]\null\enditemize}\smallskip
    \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}%{\itemize\item[]\null\enditemize}\smallskip
    \begin{itemize}
        \item text
        \item text
        \item text
    \end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The expected effect is:

[image]

Comment: In this way you're adding a possible page break point between the theorem label and the body. I don't think you should do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `ntheorem` package already defines a `break`style, so the code is quite simple. Note there is no unnecessary paragraph indent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[thmmarks, thref, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[test]
\blindtext
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: It works fine if the theorem body has a list (with the help of the `enumitem` package:

```
\begin{theorem}[another test]
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt]
  \item Some text. 
  \item Some more text
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}
```

[image]

Comment: I was aware of this, but the point here is to make it work when the content of this theorem begins with a `itemize` or `enumerate` list. The default one in `ntheorem` is not very different from the one defined with `amsthm`.

Comment: @Jinwen: I've added an example of how it works with a list.

Comment: Thank you for this! I took a look at the code in `ntheorem` and fixed my `amsthm` version. I didn't mark your answer as accepted because it is not a direct answer to the original question, but I upvoted it as it helped to solve my *real* question.